# How to make all table cells center aligned?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have this code which works fine

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Table Data }  
\centering          
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}    % centered columns (4 columns)
```

Now i have the dynamic headers so i have to hard code this line every time accoring to headers

```
begin{tabular}{c c c c}
```

is there any way to apply that to all coumns instead of all like this

```
begin{tabular}{c} for all
```

Comment: You can use, for example, `\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}` to indicate five columns of `c` type.

Comment: so it means i need to know before hand how many columns should be there

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a number of columns which is more that you need -- there is no problem with extra column specification, AFAIK.  Also, as per Gonzalo Medina's comment you can use the `{*{15}{c}}` notation to specify a maximum of 15 columns.

[image]

### Notes:

- I also recommend using [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) for more professional looking table.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}      
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c} \toprule
One & Two \\ \cmidrule{1-2}
 1  & 2   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{*{15}{c}} \toprule
One & Two & Three \\ \cmidrule{1-3}
 1  & 2   & 3 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```